# Http_user_agent not detected in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to block some user agents but NGinx seems not to see it.

I did use the map
calling the map from the http section and having the test in the server section (like show on many tutorials)

```
map $http_user_agent $badagent {
    default         0;
  ~*archive.org_bot 1;
  ~*Anemone         1;
  ~*Ant.com         1;
  ~*Baidu           1;
  ~*Bot/1.0         1;
  ~*Companybook     1;
  ~*Go-http-client  1;
  ~*Pcore-HTTP      1;
}
```

then in the server section

```
if ($badagent) {
  return 444;
}
```

i've tried that too

```
if ($badagent = 1) {
  return 444;
}
```

to make it easier i even tried that :

```
if ($http_user_agent="Mozilla") {return 404;}
```

and

```
if ($http_user_agent = "Mozilla") {return 404;}
```

there is no error, but even after restart, my browser is not blocked. What did i did wrong ?

Comment: The `map` looks fine. Use `nginx -T` to view the configuration that Nginx is reading. The ` $http_user_agent="Mozilla"` statement will not match your user agent. The user agent string is much longer than that. See the access log for the exact user agent strings.

Comment: thanks. Migrating from Apache to NGinx is not as simple as i thought. The conf is fully read. I have tried that in the server section without more success : 
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "Mozilla") {return 404;}
    if ($http_user_agent ~* Mozilla) {return 404;}
with this way, it is not necessary to write the full user agent string, right ?

Comment: stupid question but is there a need of a specific module to handle the info ? here are the installed http modules 
http_auth_request_module
http_ssl_module
http_v2_module
http_realip_module
http_addition_module
http_xslt_module=dynamic
http_image_filter_module=dynamic
http_geoip_module=dynamic
http_sub_module
http_dav_module
http_flv_module
http_mp4_module
http_gunzip_module
http_gzip_static_module
http_random_index_module
http_secure_link_module
http_degradation_module
http_slice_module
http_stub_status_module
http_perl_module=dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I have a nginx.conf file AND a mydomain.conf file.

Whenever the instruction was in my main nginx.conf file (that is parsed and part of the config), the instruction/test was not taken into consideration.
But as soon as i moved the intruction in mydomain.conf file, then everything was working fine.